# How to set starting selected item in subnav?

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

How do you set the default selected 'li' in a 'subnav' display?
Also can the text of the active/selected 'li' be set to bold?

Answer (score 1):

To make an item selected, you give an `li` element the active class.

```html
<li><a class="nav-link active">Link 3</a></li>
```

https://clarity.design/documentation/sidenav

If you are using Angular, you can use the `[ngRouterActive]="active"` directive to automatically assign the class if the route is active.

https://angular.io/guide/router